# .live not working in jQuery in Google Chrome but working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, client-side-scripting

I am trying to open a dialog on click of a anchor tag.

Code as follows:

```
 <td class="tdalign" title="@item.DupeYCode">    
     @Html.ActionLink(item.DupeYCode == "" ? " " : item.DupeYCode, "", "", new { id = item.RefundTicketNo }, new { @class = "HyperlinkText" , id= "DupeYRow", Attr = item.RefundTicketNo })
 </td>
```

On click of id selector  i am trying to  open a .Dialog in jquery.

```
$("#DupeYRow").live("click", function (e) {       
//debugger;   
  });
```

It is working on IE but on Chrome it is not working.
The Reference Files for jqyery I am using is as follows:

```
  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/icon-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

   @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")
```

Please let me know how can i get it on debugger in chrome also using id selector.
I have tried using class selector too.But it is still not working on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixed up two different version of jquery.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")
```

so at first remove one.(suggestion:- last one )

Use the `on()` method instead of `live()`.(update **@Siva Ganesh** answer).

1.If your **Script** and **HTML** in same page then use:

```
$("#DupeYRow").on('click', function(e) {

   e.preventdefault();
  // what you want
    return false;
});
```

2.If you are use external file then use:

```
  $(document).on('click','#DupeYRow',function(e) {

       e.preventdefault();
      // what you want
        return false;
  });
```

Comment: still its on coming on the debugger when running the program on chrome browser

Comment: Yes, thanks to @Ashiquzzaman, on chrome or just anyother browser, just make sure to change from `$(document).live` to `$(document).on` which will work just fine does not matter which browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**You mixed up your jquery version. Follow "Ashiquzzaman" idea**

```
The `live()` method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the `on()` method instead.

$("#DupeYRow").on('click', function(e) {
    // what you want
});
```

Comment: $("#DupeYRow").on("click", function (e) {
            //It is still not comming on Debugger in IE
        });

Comment: No it is not working......what i have written above i have wrote the same code in MVC.But it is still not working.

Comment: On is also giving me the same result as .live is giving..Do i need to add some other version Jquery Reference Files

Comment: wait bro lets i take a look and tell